# Retrieve password for a given user in wsadmin

Tags: websphere, wsadmin

I am using jython script - wsadmin - admintask command for changing the password. However before that I need to check for current password of the user in WAS. Is there any way / command I can retreive the password of a given user from WAS using wsadmin tool

Thanks

Comment: So you want, say, an admin user to be able to retrieve the current password of a different user? (I don't have an answer right now, just trying to clarify the question.)

Answer (score 0):

There is no way you can do it form WAS( Assuming here user you are referring is in ldap).